# Change Column Name in a report

Tags: civireport

Where would I go to change a column name in a report? I need an event summary report. There are 2 columns that list out the Registered/Attended/Pending etc. Those column names are very long and I would like to use this report on our dashboard. It would be nice if I could just say Participant Count.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this - but the easy no-coding way is to use the "Word Replacements" function.  Go to **Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Word Replacements** and put in the phrase you want to replace, along with what to replace it with.  Don't forget to check "Enabled", and next time you reload that report page, you should see your change.

For the official documentation, check here: http://gitbook.civicrm.org/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface.html